# How to merge millions of small (<1MB) files on S3?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hdfs

I have around 5 million small (800kB) files that are stored on AWS S3. I want to merge them into larger files of ~100MB each, because the doing a map reduce job on 5 million small files has bad performance.

What is a good way to merge these files? I'd like to do it quickly and efficiently. I'm open to using MapReduce, S3 API's, whatever gets the job done well.

Comment: Try using S3Distcp to move the files into a new location